# 'qt.qpa.screen: Could not connect to display' error when run python script at boot

Tags: shell-script, cron, raspbian, python3

I have searched this problem online but could not resolve it. Excuse my inexperience. 
I am trying to run a python script on startup which uses PyQt5 library to create a window. I am using a raspberry pi 3 model b+, and raspbian buster with lxde.
I wrote a shell script as follows:

```
#! /bin/bash
sleep 10
python3 /home/pi/Desktop/workfolder/mainwindow.py
```

Then I have added this into crontab.

```
@reboot /home/pi/Desktop/workfolder/startup.sh > /home/pi/Documents/error.log 2>&1
```

When I reboot, error log gives me the following error.

```
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Could not connect to any X display.
```

I had some other issues which I was able to solve but I am stuck at this one. When I run my script via terminal, my screen does start. As far as I know, Xorg is installed since lxde is running. 
I have also changed sleep 10 to sleep 30 to make sure if script was not running too early. But still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Timeout is not the greatest problem.

Use `DISPLAY=:0` to specify where to display the window:

```
@reboot DISPLAY=:0 /home/pi/Desktop/workfolder/startup.sh > /home/pi/Documents/error.log 2>&1
```